# Run code formatter from the command line with PhpStorm open

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

If I go to my PhpStorm\bin folder I can run the format.bat command to format files from the command line e.g.

```
phpstorm format -r C:\path\to\my\code -r -s c:\path\to\my\settings.xml
```

and that works great. However I cannot run the command if PhpStorm is open, I get an error:

> Only one instance of PhpStorm can be run at a time

Not ideal to have to close my IDE or have to use a 3rd party code formatter. Is there any workaround? Without installing another copy of PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160462

Answer (score 0):

The link from y.bedrov led me to here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter with a potential solution.

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to get it to work, I had to resort to copying my PhpStorm directory and using the copy instead. But I add it here in hopes that it helps others

## Running Command-Line Formatter when the IDE is Running

## On Linux/MacOS

- Go to /bin directory where  is a directory where Intellij IDEA or Intellij IDEA-based product is installed.
- Copy idea.properties to some other file, for example, format.properties
- Modify format.properties as follows:
- Uncomment the lines:

  - # idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/config
  - # idea.system.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system
- Change them to point to some directories which differ from defaults, for example:

  - idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/format/config
  - idea.system.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/format/system

Modify format.sh by adding the line with IDEA_PROPERTIES variable:

```
\#!/bin/sh
\# ------------------------------------------------------
\# IntelliJ IDEA formatting script.
\# ------------------------------------------------------

IDE_BIN_HOME="${0%/*}"
export IDEA_PROPERTIES=$IDE_BIN_HOME/format.properties
exec "$IDE_BIN_HOME/idea.sh" format "$@"
```

Run format.sh without closing the IDE, it should give the following output:

```
IntelliJ IDEA ..., build ... Formatter
Usage: format [-h] [-r|-R] [-s|-settings settingsPath] path1 path2...
  -h|-help       Show a help message and exit.
  -s|-settings   A path to Intellij IDEA code style settings .xml file.
  -r|-R          Scan directories recursively.
  -m|-mask       A comma-separated list of file masks.
  path..         A path to a file or a directory.
```

## On Windows

You have to create a separate format.properties file as described above for Linux/MacOS.
Change format.bat file by adding a line with IDEA_PROPERTIES variable as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
:: IntelliJ IDEA formatting script.
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
SET IDE_BIN_DIR=%~dp0
SET IDEA_PROPERTIES=%IDE_BIN_DIR%\format.properties
CALL "%IDE_BIN_DIR%\idea.bat" format %*
```

Run format.bat, it will list the command-line formatter options.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter) works for me. But ensure use `PHPSTORM_PROPERTIES` instead of `IDEA_PROPERTIES` when export environment variable as described in the article:

```bash
export IDEA_PROPERTIES=$IDE_BIN_HOME/format.properties
```

And what's more, from version 2022.1, IntelliJ IDEA supports `dry run` which is very useful for format validation based pre-commit git hook.